# Lambda expression - For a Select New

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, collections, lambda

I am trying to create a custom collection from an IQueryable object, where i am trying to perform a select statement but getting an error cannot convert to store expression. I am new to Lambda Expression. Kindly help me how to fix this problem.

Getting error at line c.Event.FirstUpper()

```
public static string FirstCharToUpper(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return string.Empty;

    var trimmed = input.Trim();
    return trimmed.First().ToString().ToUpper() + trimmed.Substring(1);
}


public static Expression<Func<string, string>> GetFirstCaseToUpperExpression()
{
    var expression = NJection.LambdaConverter.Fluent.Lambda.TransformMethodTo<Func<string, string>>()
                             .From(() => StringFormatter.FirstCharToUpper)
                             .ToLambda();
     return expression;
}
```

Calling the Expression

```
return new List<LoggerModel>( 
    logDB.PELoggers
         .Where(c => (c.SubscriberCode == SubscriberCode)).OrderByField(sortBy, ascendingOrder).Select(c => new LoggerModel()
                   {
                       DateTime = c.DateTime.Value,
                       Event = c.Event.FirstUpper()
                   })
```

Comment: Basically EF or whatever DB linq provider you are using does not know how to convert your method into SQL.  Try putting an `AsEnumerable` before the `Select` so it will run your code in memory instead.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using Entity Framework or a smiliar O/R mapper.

Think about what you are doing here: you are writing a LINQ query that should be executed against your database. To do this, it will translate your LINQ query into a SQL query which will then be executed against your database.

But `FirstCharToUpper()` is a custom method in your code. Your database does not know anything about it, so your O/R mapper's LINQ provider cannot translate it into anything meaningful in SQL, hence you get the error.

So what you need to do is to first "finish" the query against your database to have the results in-memory and after that, apply any further processing that can only be done within the boundaries of your code on that in-memory collection.

You can do this simply by inserting `.AsEnumerable()` in your LINQ query before you do the select with your custom expression:

```
logDB.PELoggers
    .Where(c => (c.SubscriberCode == SubscriberCode))
    .OrderByField(sortBy, ascendingOrder)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new LoggerModel()
        {
            DateTime = c.DateTime.Value,
            Event = c.Event.FirstUpper()                       
        })
```

When calling `AsEnumerable()`, the query against your database will be executed and the results are copied into an `IEnumerable` in memory. The `Select()` afterwards will now already be executed against the in-memory collection and not against the database anymore, thus it can use your custom `FirstCharToUpper()` method.

---

**Edit based on your comments below:**

Everything above is still valid, but in the comments you said your function needs to return `IQueryable`. In your case, what your `FirstCharToUpper()` method is doing is pretty simple and the LINQ-to-Entities provider does support methods like `ToUpper` and `Substring`. So I'd recommend to simply get rid of your helper method and instead write your LINQ query to do just that with methods that Entity Framework can translate to valid SQL:

```
logDB.PELoggers
    .Where(c => (c.SubscriberCode == SubscriberCode))
    .OrderByField(sortBy, ascendingOrder)
    .Select(c => new LoggerModel()
        {
            DateTime = c.DateTime.Value,
            Event = c.Event.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
                    + c.Event.Substring(1)                       
        })
```

This will result in a SQL query that will already return the content in Event with an uppercase first letter right from the database.

To also support the `IsNullOrEmpty` check and the `Trim` you are doing (both also supported by LINQ-to-Entities) I recommend to change the lambda syntax to the LINQ query syntax so you can use the `let` statement for the trimming, which makes the code cleaner:

```
from c in logDB.PELoggers
let trimmedEvent = c.Event.Trim()
where c.SubscriberCode == SubscriberCode
select new LoggerModel()
    {
        DateTime = c.DateTime.Value,
        Event = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedEvent)
                ? trimmedEvent.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() 
                  + trimmedEvent.Substring(1)
                : string.Empty
    };
```

In case you do not want to have this done in the LINQ query, you would need to do the uppercasing at some point later when your query against the DB has been executed, for example right in the View that will show your data. Or one option could be to apply the uppercasing in the `Event` property setter of your `LoggerModel`:

```
public class LoggerModel
{
    // ...
    private string event;

    public string Event
    { 
        get { return event; }
        set { event = FirstCharToUpper(value); }
    }
    // ...
}
```

But there is no way to make custom functions work inside LINQ-to-Entities queries.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however there is a catch. If i want to return a PagedList with which accepts IQueryable with page number and total number of records per page - it wouldn't allow right ? I am choosing IQueryable over IEnumerable because of the Performance and fetch only limited records from DB. So i cant write a expression make the SQL understand ?

Comment: return new PagedList<LoggerModel>( 
        logDB.PELoggers
                   .Where(c => (c.SubscriberCode == SubscriberCode)).OrderByField(sortBy, ascendingOrder).Select(c => new LoggerModel()
                   {

                       DateTime = c.DateTime.Value,

                       Event = c.Event.FirstUpper()                       


                   }) , 1, 100);

Comment: In this case, considering your `FirstCharToUpper()` method is pretty simple and uses methods that Entity Framework can translate to SQL, I'd recommend to get rid of it and use ToUpper and Substring right in the LINQ query. I updated the answer with an example. All assuming you are using a recent version of Entity Framework.